# Stuck with writing a function that returns a large list of nouns in a dictionary form (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Declaration: I apologise if I have not explicitly expressed my problem and I am not exactly looking for someone to code this for me, yet give me a lead on how to break this down into smaller tasks (would be a good opportunity to learn if i knew how to break it down).

I have a file full of nouns (est 500). My goal is to pluralize each word within the file. There are a few ways to pluralize a word depending on how the word ends. Either ending with 's', 'es', 'ies' and so on..

The function I am aiming to write takes one argument.

```
def pluralize (word)
```

and outputs:

```
{'plural': word_in_plural, 'status' : x}
```

**word_in_plural** is the pluralized version of the input argument **word** and **x** is a string which can have one of values: **'empty_string'**, **'proper_noun'**, **'already_in_plural'**, **'success'**.

Really have no clue on how to break this down, i've been going through lecture videos for the last 3 hours and its got me no-where.

I would rather not waste your time with these queries and want to follow SOF etiquette. I apologise in advance if im asking incorrectly.

If anyone could provide a point in the right direction, I would be very grateful. All the best.

Comment: What rules do you expect to use to decide what pluralisation ending to use?

Comment: Assume a word is in plural if it ends with 's'. Also, make the strong assumption that there are no singular words in English ending with 's'. "Note that your function should
convert any capitalized input to lower case first because the proper nouns in the list
are all lower case. The values in your output dictionary, however, will retain the
original capitalization".

As for rules of pluralization:
if word ends with vowel, add 's'.
if ends in 'y' and is preceded by consonant, erase last letter and add- ies. 
if ends in 'f' erase last Conso. and add 'ves'.

Comment: if ends with 'sc'/'ch'/'z', add '-es'
if none of the above apply, just add 's'.
After these rules, output should present itself as mentioned above.

there is so much going on here im drowning.

Comment: do i need to import a particular module?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the python pattern lib:

```
import pattern.en

print (pattern.en.pluralize("house"))
```

Output:

```
houses
```

To install:

```
pip3 install pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and break the problem down into parts. I feel like that helps me think about and simplify more complex code and it lets me test it as I go.

First off the main organization of the function, If the pluralization were just to add s every time then you might be able to do something like this.

```
def pluralize(word):
  output = dict()
  output["plural"] = word + "s" #replace this line later with better logic
  output["status"] = "success" #replace this line later with better logic
  return output
```

To do a pluralization based on the ending of the word you could compare the ending of the word to another string that you have already defined. If statements would work just fine

```
if word[-1] in {'a','e','i','o','u'}:
  output["plural"] = word + 's'
elif word[-1] == 's':
  output["plural"] = word + "es"
#add more conditions here as needed
else:
  output["plural"] = word + 's'
```

additional if statements could be added as needed.

for the status you can add an if, elif, else at the to check for what you need. For example

```
if word == '':
  output["status"] = "empty_string"
#add other conditions as needed
```

I hope this gives you something to start with.

Python also requires that indentation lines up and tab characters are not the same as spaces.

To make a string lower case in python you can use `word.lower()`

Best of luck with your application.